# How to configure custom ribbon toolbar buttons to Page Metadata Schema?

Tags: configuration, gui-extensions, rtf

I created new ribbon tool bar buttons for RTF fields. I am able to see them in component RTF fields. But when I add a metadata schema with RTF field to a page I am unable to see the custom buttons in the ribbon toolbar, where as I am able to see OOB RTF buttons in the RTF area. Please let me know where to configure those custom buttons to reflect in Page meta data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a system to hand, but this sounds like an error in your extension.config file.

For your new toolbar you probably have added a config element which tells the system to add it to the *ComponentView* - You will need to add this to the *PageView* also. If that does not help, please include the relevant section of your extension.config in your question.

Comment: As you said only Component view is added in extension.config file, adding Page view solved the problem. It saved me a lot of time.